# SELECT COUNT in same table based on current row value within a single query

Tags: mysql, count

Let's say I have a table like below

```
uid      | value      | date_added
-----------------------------------
14152    | NA4156     | 2019-03-01
14153    | EA4656     | 2019-03-02
14152    | EA4656     | 2019-03-02
14155    | CA4456     | 2019-03-03
14153    | DA4556     | 2019-03-03
14157    | EA4656     | 2019-03-03
14155    | FA4756     | 2019-03-06
14159    | GA4856     | 2019-03-06
```

If I would like to return all data with an count based on uid

```
uid      | value      | count
-----------------------------------
14152    | NA4156     | 2
14153    | EA4656     | 3
14152    | EA4656     | 2
14155    | CA4456     | 2
14153    | DA4556     | 3
14153    | EA4656     | 3
14155    | FA4756     | 2
14159    | GA4856     | 1
```

As a limited sql user, I cannot figure out how. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example data doesn't correspond with your reszkt.
But you are looking for a INNER JOIN with a subquery

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `uid` INTEGER,
>   `value` VARCHAR(6),
>   `date_added` VARCHAR(10)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`uid`, `value`, `date_added`)
> VALUES
>   ('14152', 'NA4156', '2019-03-01'),
>   ('14153', 'EA4656', '2019-03-02'),
>   ('14152', 'EA4656', '2019-03-02'),
>   ('14155', 'CA4456', '2019-03-03'),
>   ('14153', 'DA4556', '2019-03-03'),
>   ('14157', 'EA4656', '2019-03-03'),
>   ('14155', 'FA4756', '2019-03-06'),
>   ('14159', 'GA4856', '2019-03-06');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> t1.`uid`, t1.`value`, total_count
> FROM
> table1 t1 InnER JOIN (SELECT Count(*) total_count, `uid` FROM table1 GROUP BY `uid`) t2
> ON t1.`uid` = t2.`uid`
> ```
>
> ```
>   uid | value  | total_count
> ----: | :----- | ----------:
> 14152 | NA4156 |           2
> 14153 | EA4656 |           2
> 14152 | EA4656 |           2
> 14155 | CA4456 |           2
> 14153 | DA4556 |           2
> 14157 | EA4656 |           1
> 14155 | FA4756 |           2
> 14159 | GA4856 |           1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a18c400a37a77e2a4ad48bf04d160bd5)*